# Zappa Django Rest Framework API timeout on AWS Cognito call

Tags: django, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, zappa

I'm migrating a `Django Rest Framework` API to lambdas, with Zappa
This API is also running on an Elastic Beanstalk application and works fine there.
First I got error messages while trying to connect to the database,
Then I did set the lambda VPC and security groups, and it seems that this error is gone, however, any call to the authentication endpoint (that uses Cognito) results in a timeout.

I know that API Gateway is hardcoded to timeout after 29s, but I don't think this endpoint should be taking that long.

I've enabled X-Ray, but it doesn't say much, just that the function timed out

Looking at the Cloudwatch logs I could point the moment it gets stuck

```

09:10:09
[DEBUG] 2020-03-04T09:10:09.326Z 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443

[DEBUG] 2020-03-04T09:10:09.326Z    2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443

09:10:10

09:10:30
END RequestId: 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981
END RequestId: 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981

09:10:30
REPORT RequestId: 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981 Duration: 30030.18 ms Billed Duration: 30000 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 141 MB Init Duration: 469.61 ms XRAY TraceId: 1-5e5f7067-d06b5ff2aaa8b9c6218f7444 SegmentId: 6ef0fb0d7de15cfe Sampled: true
REPORT RequestId: 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981  Duration: 30030.18 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 141 MB Init Duration: 469.61 ms    
XRAY TraceId: 1-5e5f7067-d06b5ff2aaa8b9c6218f7444   SegmentId: 6ef0fb0d7de15cfe Sampled: true   

09:10:30
2020-03-04T09:10:30.369Z 2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

As you can see, this call seems to get stuck

```
[DEBUG] 2020-03-04T09:10:09.326Z    2e2ba999-a6bf-42e0-a5f1-6b4c70e72981    Starting new HTTPS connection (1): cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
```

I tried to find if I need to setup any vpc/security group on the Cognito, but haven't find anything related.
Any idea what might be causing this issue?

**UPDATE**

I've checked the VPC, and there's an internet gateway associated with it

`0.0.0.0/0 ig-xxxxxxxxx active No`

this is on the route table for the VPC

Then, I have created a NAT gateway, and replaced the ig on the table by the NAT
I still get the same error.

**UPDATE 2**

There's a main route table with explicit subnet association with my subnets
Then, there's a NAT gateway linked to 1 of the subnets, and to the VPC, and with a elastic IP

If I click on any of my subnets and go to the "Route Table" tab, I see something like this

`172.31.0.0/16 local`
`0.0.0.0/0 nat-xxxxxxx`

I go to the `Network ACL` I see this:

```
Network ACL:
acl-xxxxx
Inbound rules

Rule #  Type  Protocol Port Range / ICMP Type Source Allow / Deny
100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW 
* ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 DENY

Outbound rules

Rule # Type Protocol Port Range / ICMP Type Destination Allow / Deny
100 ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW 

* ALL Traffic ALL ALL 0.0.0.0/0 DENY
```

what I am missing?

Comment: check if your security groups allow outbound access to 0.0.0.0 via a NAT Gateway. The reason I ask is because if the DB is inside the VPC it should still connect seamlessly, but Cognito uses an HTTPS endpoint which is accessible over the Internet. Your function will timeout if the configured security groups don't allow such outbound connection.

Comment: I have checked it, and there was only a Internet gateway (shouldn't be enough?), I tried replacing it with a NAT one, still the same error

Comment: Internet Gateways are used on public subnets to allow both inbound/outbound traffic. If your Lambda function is inside a VPC with private subnets only, you will need at least one NAT gateway in a public subnet to route outbound traffic. Note that the NAT Gateway needs to be in a public subnet. Long story short, it goes like this: Lambda -> SG -> NAT Gateway in public subnet -> Internet. If you want to troubleshoot it, I suggest you ignore the DB connection for now, remove the Lambda from the VPC and try connecting to Cognito. If it works, then the problem certainly lies on your VPC config.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi I've updated the questions with the steps I took, I don't understand what I'm missing, I've the NAT gateway, and it is associated with my subnet

Comment: and that NAT Gateway is associated with your *public subnet*? Then you must configure the *outbound traffic* on the security groups attached to your Lambda function to allow outbound traffic to *0.0.0.0/0*. Finally, you must edit the route tables associated to your private subnet(s) to allow outbound connections through the *NAT gateway* allocated in the public subnet. I don't see anything beyond this as far as configuration goes.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi This might be a stupid question, but where do I see the public subnet? I see only "Subnets", can't see how to determine whether they are public or not

Comment: If the subnet has an Internet Gateway attached to it, then it is public. If it has a NAT Gateway, then it is private.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi It worked! Thanks!
You can summarize it on an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Nah, it's fine. I'm in one of those too-lazy-to-create-an-answer sort of days. I am glad it worked :)